# What types of components can you put in the pre-assemble stage of a biztalk pipeline?

Tags: biztalk

I want to put a custom component that removes a namespace in the pre-assemble stage of biztalk pipeline. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a pipeline component in the BizTalk ESB toolkit that handles removing a namespace. Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649945.aspx